# How to open design window on VS 2019 for mysql database table?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a windows form app with visual studio 2019. I have connected to MySQL. When I right click on tables and click create table this error pops up

[Cannot create a design window for the selected object. Creation failed with message: The requested .NET Framework Date Provider was not found. Please confirm that Connector/NET is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9tFE.png)

I have Connector/NET version 8.0.29 installed on MySQL installer. And MySQL for Visual Studio installed as well. How do I create tables in visual studio?

Here is my installer - [MySQL installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XLBY.png)

VS shows a connection - [Server Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYMaC.png)

Answer (score 1):

So I never could get the VS table to open up, maybe it's not the ideal way. So I have just been going to MySQL workbench and updating the table there and carrying the information over.

Comment: MySqlWB will likely provide a superior database design interface to anything Vs offers, though I appreciate the desire to do it all in one place. If you're using entity framework, you could do code first and let migrations do most of the work

Answer (score 0):

the reason may be that the version of the mysql connection database plug-in is wrong. You can change the version of the downloaded connector, and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I attempted to back up to 8.0.28 and when I went back to VS to start the connection again an error message popped up saying that this error is generally activated when VS is not installed correctly.